# What is a WW1 water detail?

Tags: military

Looking at my grandfathers files from Canadian military archives WW 1.
He was in the medical corps as a stretcher bearer. One of his tasks was
to be put on water detail. Would anyone know what being on water detail would encompass ?

Comment: I don't feel qualified to give a full answer. This thing I found explains it. http://www.vlib.us/medical/coll256.htm 
-Daily supervision of water-supply and its purification for drinking purposes by boiling, filtration, or the addition of chemicals, as may be directed.
-Charge of all apparatus and stores connected with the water-supply of the unit.

The Water Detail takes charge of the water-carts with the unit, and the issue of water to the troops. Where natural water-supplies are used, they are responsible for the care of the watering-places, and will regulate the use of same.

Comment: @Almo - I think in this case, if you are capable of clicking the "Post your answer" button, you are probably qualified. :-)

Comment: ask  Indy

https://www.youtube.com/user/TheGreatWar

Comment: @T.E.D. haha ok, there it is. :)

Answer (score 25):

An excerpt from this site

http://www.vlib.us/medical/coll256.htm

which describes itself as

> The following lecture on Sanitation and Hygiene is taken from the
>   book, "Military Organisation and Administration" published by Major G.
>   R. N. Collins, 4th. Battn. Canadians Instructor, Canadian Military
>   School, in 1918. Major Collins was incapacitated from general service
>   in the field and was appointed to the Canadian Military School where
>   he gave lectures to several thousands of Officers of the Canadian
>   Forces.

describes what a "water detail" is:

> The Regimental Water Detail is posted to the unit from the Medical
>   Corps, the numbers varying according to the size of the unit. They are
>   responsible for--
>
> 1. Daily supervision of water-supply and its purification for drinking purposes by boiling, filtration, or the addition of chemicals, as may
>      be directed.
> 2. Charge of all apparatus and stores connected with the water-supply of the unit.
>
> The Water Detail takes charge of the water-carts with the unit, and
>   the issue of water to the troops. Where natural water-supplies are
>   used, they are responsible for the care of the watering-places, and
>   will regulate the use of same.

Comment: 1918, after being incapacitated in the field? And Canadian to boot? Not sure how much more authoritative than this it can get.

Comment: The skeptic in me says, "anybody can put any text on a web page" and without going and checking the alleged source material, how reliable is a web page? But you're right. This does look like a really good source.

Comment: Well, if someone is really wanting to check, here appears to be a [copy of the book online](https://archive.org/details/militaryorganiza00colluoft/page/n7).

Comment: Wow, that's really cool. Looks like it's signed in '33.